# Parse Oplog(mongodb) with mongo-oplog node.js package

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using the mongo-oplog package in order to create an insert listener to a mongodb.

```
var MongoOplog = require('mongo-oplog');
var oplog = MongoOplog('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/local').tail();

oplog.on('op', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});

oplog.on('insert', function (doc) {
    console.log(doc.op);
});

oplog.on('error', function (error) {
    //catch the error -> do nothing
});
```

As a result, i am getting responses in this format :

```
{ ts: { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 1, high_: 1437408655 },
  h: { _bsontype: 'Long', low_: -681831757, high_: 1089307960 },
  v: 2,
  op: 'i',
  ns: 'mongoapp.British',
  o: 
   { _id: 55ad1d8f2d98983c1d15413a,
     user: 'lalala',
     language: 'en',
     location: '',
     time: 'Mon Jul 20 16:10:54 +0000 2015',
     text: 'First the flight was delayed and now my luggage is missing #britishairways.' } }
i
```

My question is : Is there a way to parse this ? I want specifically to be able to parse the text field in order to make changes. Is this possible ?

Comment: Not sure about the exact implementation, but Meteor does something like that. The relevant code should be available at https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/mongo

Comment: The thing is that i don't know meteor and my script is quite simple. What i am not understanding is what king of object "doc.op" is. If its not parsable then i should like into more complex solution like meteor.